# Redirecting to the root using javascript

Tags: javascript

In my project I have the following script in order to open a page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setPage(pName) {
    var iPage = "'" + pName + "'";
    document.getElementById('iFrame').src = window.location.href(iPage);
}
</script>
```

when I run the program it gives me the following problematic url:

```
Requested URL
   http://localhost:7819/Pages/Account/'http:/localhost:7819/Pages/Support/Asp/Help01.aspx'
```

As we see the address contain the url of the current page plus the requested url.
More of it I'm loosing the second slash `/` in `http:/` which I have it all the way inside the script.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `href` isn't a function, you should be getting an error from `window.location.href(iPage)`.

Comment: From MDN: "in most cases: window.location = 'http://www.example.com' is a synonym of window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'."

Comment: and you certainly don't need to add quotes to your iPage variable.

Comment: Did you actually write `.src = iPage;`? That would be more consistent with the result you're getting.

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to make the iframe's `src` equal to the parent's `href` *plus something*?

Comment: If `pName` contains: `/Pages/Support/Asp/Help01.aspx`, then you should try this: `document.getElementById('iFrame').src = pName;`

Comment: Thank you very much all. You've been very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you wanted something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setPage(pName) {
        document.getElementById('iFrame').src = pName;
    }
</script>
```